# Transforming Dataset with only 0 and 1 values

Tags: r, data-transform

I'm unsure of what to call this, so I'll try to describe in laymens terms what the issue is. I have a dataframe that only consists of 0 and 1. So for each individual instead of having one column with a factoral value (ex. low price, 4 rooms) I have

```
      V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10 V11 V12 V13 V14 V15 V16 V17 V18 V19 V20 V21
1     0  0  0  1  0  0  0  1  0   1   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   1   0
2     1  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  1   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   1   0   0   1
3     0  0  0  1  1  0  0  0  0   0   1   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   1   0   0
4     0  0  0  1  0  1  0  0  0   0   1   0   1   0   0   0   1   0   1   0   0
```

How can I transform the dataset in R, so that I create new columns (#number of rooms) and give the position of the 1 (in the 4th column) a vhigh value? 
I have multiple expenatory varibales I need to do this for. the 21 columns are representing 6 variables for 1000+ observations. should be something like this

```
     PurchaseP.   NumberofRooms ...
1.      vhigh.         4
2.      low.           4
3.      vhigh.         1
4.      vhigh.         2
```

Just did it for the first 2 epxlenatory varibales here, but essentially it repeats like this with each explenatory variable has 3-4 possible factoral values.

V1:V4 = purchase price, V5:V8 = number of rooms,V9:V11 = floors, and so on

In my head something like this could work

1. create a if statemt to give each 1 a value depending on column position, ex. if  value in V4=1 then name "vhigh". and do this for each Vx
2. Then combine each column V1:V4, V5:V8, V9:V11 (depending on if it has 3-4 possible factoral/integer values) while ignoring 0 values.

Would this work, or is there a simpler approach? How would one code this in R?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function which() similar to

```
lapply(df, function(x) { %now x is a row
    idx = which(x == 1)[1] 
    return(idx)
    })
```

The interesting part is to use `which(x ==1)` on each row. This gives you an array of all indices that contain a one. The first of those can be used in your case (assuming that you only have one 1 per line) Otherwise, aggregation needs to be discussed. The resulting column can then be transformed into a factor by giving sensible names to the various indices.

Comment: not entirely following here, I think I need to transform the 1s into something else before returning an array of 1s as their position within the 0s indicates their actual value. and yes sorry for not making it clear from the begining, but there are multiple 1s per row.

Answer (score 0):

If the dataset contains a single 1 per row this is a pretty simple problem

Here your data according to your picture (please edit your question to put a code instead of picture)

```
df = data.frame(r1 = 0, r2 = 1, r3 = 0)
rownames(df)<- 1
```

Then, you simply have to sum your column with the room number as weight

```
df$room = df$r1*1 + df$r2 * 2 + df$r3 *3
```

Comment: I changed it to code now, and as you can see there are multiple 1s per row.

Comment: Please edit again to show us what is the expected output because I do not understand the question. Thanks.

Comment: hope it makes more sense now, thanks for being patient.